# How can I iterate over a TGroupBox and check the state of its children?

Tags: c++, user-interface, firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

Using C++ Builder 10.4 Community edition, I have a `TGroupBox` populated with some `TCheckbox` and `TButton` controls. I want to iterate over the `TGroupBox` to get the state of each `TCheckBox`. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
auto control = groupBxLB->Controls;

for( uint8_t idx = 0; idx < groupBxLB->ChildrenCount; idx++) {
    if( control[idx] == TCheckBox) {
        //get the state of the TCHeckBox
    }
}
```

but no success.

Does anybody have an idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`TWinControl::Controls`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Controls) property is not an object of its own, so you can't assign it to a local variable, the way you are trying to.

Also, there is no `ChildrenCount` property in `TWinControl`. The correct property name is [`ControlCount`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ControlCount) instead.

The C++ equivalent of Delphi's [`is` operator](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References#The_is_Operator) in this situation is to use [`dynamic_cast`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Dynamic_cast_(C%2B%2B_Type_Cast_Operator)) ([cppreference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)) and check the result for `NULL`.

Try this:

```cpp
for(int idx = 0; idx < groupBxLB->ControlCount; ++idx) {
    TCheckBox *cb = dynamic_cast<TCheckBox*>(groupBxLB->Controls[i]);
    if (cb != NULL) {
        // use cb->Checked as needed...
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You did not make it clear in your original question that you wanted a solution for FMX. What I posted above is for VCL instead.  The FMX equivalent would look more like this:

```cpp
auto controls = groupBxLB->Controls;

for(int idx = 0; idx < controls->Count; ++idx) {
    TCheckBox *cb = dynamic_cast<TCheckBox*>(controls->Items[idx]);
    if (cb != NULL) {
        // use cb->IsChecked as needed...
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried but two errors : 1) [bcc64 Error] UI_Form_UPROG.cpp(48): no member named 'ControlCount' in 'Fmx::Stdctrls::TGroupBox'. 2) [bcc64 Error] UI_Form_UPROG.cpp(49): 'System::Generics::Collections::TList__1<TControl *>' is not a pointer.

Comment: @RASC you did not make it clear in your original question indicated you wanted a solution for FMX. What I posted is for VCL instead. I have updated my answer.